# ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

I have uncommented all things required to enable admin,
uncommented 3 lines in urls and add django.ontrib.admin in install app,
but when I open :8000/admin, it shows **View doesn't exist at /admin/

Could not import users.views.upload. View does not exist in module users.views**

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in you urlconfig somewhere. You are trying to reference a view `users.views.upload` which does not exist. The error most likely has nothing to do with Django Admin. Without the urlconfig it is very difficult to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with django, even i has faced this issue in various place, so where should I go and check for this error

Comment: Its in the urlconfig so check them

Comment: Ok, thanks the problm was exactly in my url config, thanks a lot